# Error when trying to do 'Hyperparameter Optimization' using Parallel Computing in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, machine-learning, parallel-processing, hyperparameters

I am trying to optimize the function fitrsvm.

But when I set 'true' to the 'UseParallel' property, I am getting a error.

This is the code:
.
.

```
svm_model = fitrsvm(X,Y,...
'OptimizeHyperparameters','all',...
'HyperparameterOptimizationOptions',...
struct('UseParallel',true));
```

.
.
This is the error: 
.
.

```
Error using classreg.learning.paramoptim.parseFitoptimizingArgs>validateAndCompleteStructFields (line 171)
Unrecoginized field passed in 'HyperparameterOptimizationOptions' struct: UseParallel.
```

.
.
I check this MathWorks page:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/parallel_bayesian_optimization.html
and try to follow the instructions but it is not working.

There is the fitrsvm function page too: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrsvm.html

How can I solve this? Version of MATLAB: 2017a

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Matlab staff [said](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/425634-error-when-trying-to-do-hyperparameter-optimization-using-parallel-computing) that:

"as the [Release Notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/release-notes.html) show, parallel hyperparameter optimization was added to Bayesian optimization in R2017b."